# How would this argument be properly escaped in PHP?

Tags: php, escaping

My site has some PHP generated content which echoes HTML elements. Some of these elements are responsive to javascript events...for one input element, the relevant event is `onmouseout`, but I can't seem to escape this properly.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT stuff1, stuff2, stuff100, tags FROM myTable WHERE user_id = 'myID'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $Tagstring = $row['tags'];
    //lots of code

    echo "<div class='myClass1 myClass2'>
            <input type='text' name='myInput' value='".$Tagstring."' onmouseout='ajaxFunction(\"myString\", this.value.trim().replace(/,\s|\s,/g, ","))'>
          </div>";
    //more code
}
```

$Tagstring is a comma-separated string of text substrings. If a user edits his/her tags, I am trying to prevent the following:

```
$Tagstring = 'tag1,tag2'; //from database table

//User edits to 'tag1, tag2';

//Pointless ajax call and access of server, since if user input = original $Tagstring, this will return false as I have set up the ajax call, but if user input !== $Tagstring, then ajax function proceeds
```

I am not new to PHP and Javascript, so I know in PHP about str_replace or exploding the user input on "," and then trimming each member of the explode array. Alternatively, I could use Javascript to split on "," and then trim the pieces in a for loop (or something similar).

Can anyone tell me how to properly escape the following argument in my echoed function call?

```
this.value.trim().replace(/,\s|\s,/g, ",")
```

Comment: For large `echo`, it's simpler to close and then reopen the PHP tags.

Comment: `$TagString` is not the same as `$Tagstring`.

Comment: OK...the typo has been fixed...my mistake

Comment: Now you have a syntax error. You closed the string too early.

Comment: @Blackhole....it would be hard to do this since the div is pretty large and complex (not shown) and changes HTML, text, and classes based on user input

Comment: @Sverri M. Olson...OK, which string? Any way to escape the this.value at end of post?

Comment: In the PHP code, where you `echo` a string. There is a dangling `</div>";`.

Comment: OK...fixed it. Any ideas on how to properly escape this.value at end of post? After all, this was a question about escaping and my wife just came home, so sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it...it seemed to be an escaping issue. This worked :

```
onmouseout='ajaxFunction(\"AStringNotAVariable\", this.value.trim().replace(/,\s|\s,/g, \",\"))'
```

whereas

```
//.replace(/,\s|\s,/g, ",") and .replace(/,\s|\s,/g, ',') and .replace(/,\s|\s,/g, \',\')
```

led to errors such as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 1):

I tend to echo my output opposite of the way you have done it, which I feel is easier to control. Single quotes on the outside, and double quotes on the inside.

```
echo '<div class="myClass1 myClass2">
            <input type="text" name="myInput" value="'.$TagString.'" onmouseout="ajaxFunction("myString", this.value.trim().replace(/,\s|\s,/g, ""))">
     </div>';
```

What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Try this with the code I gave you `<input type="text" name="myInput" value="'.$TagString.'" onmouseout="ajaxFunction(''myString'', this.value.trim().replace(/,\s|\s,/g, ""))">`

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)...I know it's the replace portion of the this.value because as soon as the replace gets removed to yield this.value.trim(), no more 500 –

Comment: Even though the error disappears with `\"myString\"` I don't believe that is the issue. Since PHP is controlling the output, the client side sees it as if it was html. Is "myString" a variable or something?

Comment: Fixed it...need a comma not empty string (my bad) but regardless it seemed to be an escaping issue. I used : .replace(/,\s|\s,/g, \",\"), whereas .replace(/,\s|\s,/g, ",") and .replace(/,\s|\s,/g, ',') and .replace(/,\s|\s,/g, \',\') led to errors such as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: weird, glad you got it fixed.